# loop in GCP datastore (NDB)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

How to loop through entities in GCP datastore ?

We would like to loop each user in the datastore and update based on it's status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use Datastore Queries to achieve this.

[Link to Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node js, try some like this :

```
    datastore.runQuery(query, (err,entities) => {
        var searches = [];
        if(typeof entities !== 'undefined' && entities.length > 0) {
            var keys = entities.map(function(entity) {
                searches.push(entity);
            });

            //Setting the response object
            response.status="OK";
            response.message="";
            response.data={ 
                "searches": searches
            };
        }else{
            response.status="OK";
            response.message="Empty result";
        }

        //Returning the response to client
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```